# Mongo for vs foreach

Tags: mongodb

```
for (  i = 0; i < color.length ; i++) {
  print(i);


db.products.find({"color" : color[i], "size" : size[i] }).forEach(function(product){

  print(product.barcode)})

}
```

when i run this, i can see all products printed.

But when i run this

```
for (  i = 0; i < color.length ; i++) {
  print(i);


db.products.find({"color" : color[i], "size" : size[i] },{"barcode":1})


}
```

i can only see the first product printed.

I can see

```
print(i);
```

prints all iteration indexes (i) but i only see first product.

Why?

Comment: Only first or last?

Comment: first one is seen.  so for solution, i made this ```for (  i = 0; i < color.length ; i++) {
  print(i);


db.products.find({"color" : color[i], "size" : size[i] },{"barcode":1}).forEach//and so on.


}```